# Docker run arguments/commands with Elastic Beanstalk Dockerrun.aws.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, scrapy-splash

With docker-compose you can write something like this to add arguments to the image when it runs:

```
# docker-compose.yml
splash:
    image: scrapinghub/splash:latest
    command: --max-timeout 3600 --slots 3
```

In `Dockerrun.aws.json` there is a `command` that you can specify, however it does not seem to work the same as docker-compose. You cant just add arguments like that.

So I've tried this, but it does not work:

```
# Dockerrun.aws.json
{
    "image": "scrapinghub/splash", 
    "command": ["--max-timout 3600"]
}
```

So question is, how do I get the behavior from docker-compose to my Dockerrun.aws.json file?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [container-transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform), a CLI tool that will transform docker-compose files to dockerrun format.

Edit:

If you would have followed the link, you would see an example of how container transform handles the `command` property. You need to break it up,

```
"command": ["--max-timeout", "3600"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip this was so easy to miss